# How to bin a time only timestamp in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe `df`

```
user    timestamp  amount
us67    15:59:07   87
us90    17:12:19   10
us12    03:23:16   17

print(df.timestamp[0])
>>> datetime.time(15,59,7)
```

I want to bin all the times into 1 hour intervals, so 24 intervals in total. However, I get a `TypeError`

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.cut(x=df['timestamp'], bins=24)
>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'float'
```

The method does work, however, if the date is included in the `timestamp` column, but I want to ignore the date and only keep the times (for plotting later on):

```
user    timestamp                 amount
us67    2018-04-29 15:59:07.455   87
us90    2018-04-29 17:12:19.128   10
us12    2018-04-29 03:23:16.890   17

print(df.timestamo[0])
>>> Timestamp('2018-04-29 15:59:07.455000')

df['timestamp'] = pd.cut(x=df['timestamp'], bins=24)
```

With the format above for `timestamp`, the binning works. However I don't want the year and date in the timestamp or in the intervals. I want to focus only on the time of day.

Is there a way I can bin `timestamp` using only time of day? Ultimately the goal here is to plot a timeseries of `df` (`timestamp` vs. `amount`) using the hour of day only and not the date - so if there is a better way to do that, please suggest it.

Comment: Why not just use `df['timestamp'].dt.hour` ? If you want just the time `df['timestamp'].dt.time`

Answer (score 5):

I would create a column with my binned hours using `dt.hour`

So

```
df["binned_hours"] = pd.cut(df.timestamp.dt.hour, bins=24)
```

Comment: A solution that saves the headache of working with datetime dtype if you don't have to.